# all the sliders i coded is not working pls and not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
type here
```

/ Swiper slider 2

var swiper = new swiper(".project-slider", {
slidesPerView: 1,
spaceBetween: 30,
pagination: {
el: ".project-slider .swiper-pagination",
clickable: true,
},
navigation: {
prevEl: ".project-slider .swiper-button-prev",
nextEl: ".project-slider .swiper-button-next",
},
breakpoints: {
640: {
slidesPerView: 1,
spaceBetween: 20,
},
768: {
slidesPerView: 2,
spaceBetween: 40,
},
1024: {
slidesPerView: 2,
spaceBetween: 50,
},
},
});
// End Swiper slide 2

// swiper slid

var swiper = new swiper(".swiper team-slid", {
slidesPerView: 3,
spaceBetween: 30,
pagination: {
el: ".swiper-slid box",
clickable: true,
},
});
// End swiper slide

slide to work as asign

Comment: Please take a look at your question as we see it - it's not very readable and it doesn't describe in any detail what the problem is. Look into how to provide a runnable snippet (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and how to ask a good question (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You can edit your question to improve it so we have more chance of helping you.

Comment: And are yu using some library? Please tell us what it is and remember to include it in your snippet.